# Resources that contrast and explain how to choose prepositions?

Tags: traduction, prépositions

L2 learners are disrupted and impeded by how to select and translate prepositions (even between languages of the same language family!). I know of the randomness of Functional Morphemes' semantic field, but I must still try to dig deeper.

Because most reference grammars only decree <sup>♦</sup>which preposition in isolated contexts, I must find books or resources that compare, contrast, and explain  prepositions between two languages generally. So where should I look? Please suggest books or resources.

---

<sup>♦</sup>For brevity, I exemplify from *A Comprehensive French Grammar* (2007, 6 ed) by Glanville Price:

> [p 507] 652. There is only an approximate equivalence between the
>   meanings and uses of prepositions in different languages. In figurative
>   and idiomatic expressions in particular, one language will
>   use a preposition that does not correspond to its literal equivalent
>   in another language. This is frequently so with French and English.
>   Some of the main correspondences and differences between the
>   two languages are given in the following sections, but an exhaustive
>   treatment is impossible – and does not, indeed, exist anywhere
>   else either though, to a considerable extent, uncertainties can be
>   resolved by consulting a good large dictionary.

For example, page 502 translates: **à** = `to, at`.
But then pages 507-508 demonstrate that **à** can mean *by, for, in, on, with, and within*.
So (per 652 above)  `to, at` fails to capture the [lexical field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_field_theory) of **à**.
The lexical field of **à**: what is it? What key ideas underlie it? How can you explicate it? 
[Etymologically](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0#Fran.C3.A7ais), **à** originates from the Latin *ab* and ad; but even this does not explain much.

Comment: Prepostions are badly overloaded, in French *and* in English. They don't translate outside of a context.

Comment: Moreover, it even sometimes disappear from translation in English, for example "moulin à eau" becomes "water mill"... really hard to give you a suitable answer, if ever one exists...

Answer (score 2):

Concerning works, I can't provide you any names, sry. I might enlighten you with your issue about *à*.
*à* can mean have very distincts meanings, depending on the context: place, time, means, etc. I can only recommend you the [Wikipedia page of *à*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0#fr-pr.C3.A9p) that is very complete and satisfactory (IMO at least)
I still don't advise you to look for the perfect translation for *à*, since, as for *to* or every preposition in every language, it mostly depends on the verb, and two verbs describing the same action or situation might not even use the same preposition, so... Well, grammar...